# Translate 3D position taken from CMMotionManager() to set angle on 2D CG Coordinate System

Tags: ios, swift, math, graphics, cgpoint

I don't know if this is basic math I have to compute, or my inexperience with the pitch, roll, and yaw values. At the moment I have an image object that moves based on my accelerometer values.

```
 //Move the ball based on accelerator values
        delta.x = CGFloat(acceleration.x * 10)
        delta.y = CGFloat(acceleration.y * 10)

        ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + delta.x, ball.center.y + delta.y)
```

I can calculate the pitch through the attitude and get the angle. What I want to do is line up my "ball" in the center of the screen only when the angle of the phone is a certain angle, lets say 45 degrees. How can I move my ball so that it lines up in the center based on specific angles given?

Comment: It seems you are setting the speed of the ball based on the accelerometer values. With this approach, it is not possible to force it to a specific position when a specific angle is approached. You could only make the velocity zero in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen height is `Η` pixels.
Your screen width is `W` pixels.

The horizontal centre of the screen is `x = W / 2`

I'm assuming from your question you want the ball centre to vary between the top `(x, 0)` when the screen is flat and bottom `(x, H)` when the screen is vertical.

If the angle of your phone `θ` varies between `0` and `π`, then `y = θ / π * H`

```
ball.center = CGPoint(x: W / 2, y: θ / π * H)
```

All you need is the trig to work out `θ` based on the gyro readings

Comment: Might be the right concept, but why multiply the angle times height? By doing that, the y value is in the thousands. That is, if theta is an angle in degrees.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with that, but if you don't multiply y by two then it doesn't go to the bottom of the view

Comment: My assumption was that you're working in radians, hence dividing theta by pi

Comment: Here is an update. If theta is in radians, then you still need to multiply H by two or else the ball will only get to the middle of the view, and not the bottom.